# Stop Python script running on a nao robot touching his head

Tags: python, nao-robot

My problem is the following. I have a script in Python that is executed so that the robot does perform various actions without stopping until the execution stops, however for security reasons (in case the robot goes crazy and wants to kill us all) I need to add this instruction to stop it using the touch sensor of his head in case this is pressed.

I read a little about the ALTouch module with which the TouchChanged() module can be generated, but it acts on all the sensors (including movements) and not only with the touch sensor on the head.

Any ideas or related documentation will be welcomed.

Here´s some of my code:

```
class SoundProcessingModule(object):

    def __init__( self, app):

        ttsProxy.say("Touch my head at any moment to stop me")

        super(SoundProcessingModule, self).__init__()
        app.start()
        session = app.session

        self.audio_service = session.service("ALAudioDevice")
        self.isProcessingDone = False
        self.nbOfFramesToProcess = 100
        self.framesCount=0
        self.micFront = []
        self.module_name = "SoundProcessingModule"

    def startProcessing(self):
        self.audio_service.setClientPreferences(self.module_name, 16000, 3, 0)
        self.audio_service.subscribe(self.module_name)

        while self.isProcessingDone == False:
            time.sleep(1)

        self.audio_service.unsubscribe(self.module_name)

    def processRemote(self, nbOfChannels, nbOfSamplesByChannel, timeStamp, inputBuffer):
        #ReadyToDance
        postureProxy.goToPosture("StandInit", 0.5)

        self.framesCount = self.framesCount + 1
        if (self.framesCount <= self.nbOfFramesToProcess):
            print(self.framesCount)
            self.micFront=self.convertStr2SignedInt(inputBuffer)
            rmsMicFront = self.calcRMSLevel(self.micFront)
            print ("Nivel RMS del microfono frontal = " + str(rmsMicFront))
            rmsArray.insert(self.framesCount-1,rmsMicFront)

            #-40 y -30
            if promedio >= -40 and promedio <= -30 :
                #Some dance moves    

            #-29 y -20
            elif promedio >= -29 and promedio <= -20:
                #Some dance moves

            #-19 y -11
            elif promedio >= -19 and promedio <= -11:
                #Some dance moves

        else :
            self.isProcessingDone=True
            #Plot RMS signal
            plt.plot(rmsArray)
            plt.ylabel('RMS')
            plt.xlabel('Frames')
            plt.text(np.argmin(rmsArray), np.min(rmsArray) - 0.1, u'Mínimo', fontsize=10, horizontalalignment='center',
                     verticalalignment='center')  
            plt.text(np.argmax(rmsArray), np.max(rmsArray) + 0.1, u'Máximo', fontsize=10, horizontalalignment='center',
                     verticalalignment='center')  
            print("")
            print ("El promedio total del sonido es: " + str(np.mean(rmsArray)))
            print("El maximo total del sonido es: " + str(np.max(rmsArray)))
            print("El minimo total del sonido es: " + str(np.min(rmsArray)))
            plt.show()
            postureProxy.goToPosture("Sit", 1.0)

    def calcRMSLevel(self,data) :
        rms = 20 * np.log10( np.sqrt( np.sum( np.power(data,2) / len(data)  )))
        return rms

    def convertStr2SignedInt(self, data) :
        signedData=[]
        ind=0;
        for i in range (0,len(data)/2) :
            signedData.append(data[ind]+data[ind+1]*256)
            ind=ind+2

        for i in range (0,len(signedData)) :
            if signedData[i]>=32768 :
                signedData[i]=signedData[i]-65536

        for i in range (0,len(signedData)) :
            signedData[i]=signedData[i]/32768.0

        return signedData


def StiffnessOn(proxy):
    # We use the "Body" name to signify the collection of all joints
    pNames = "Body"
    pStiffnessLists = 1.0
    pTimeLists = 1.0
    proxy.stiffnessInterpolation(pNames, pStiffnessLists, pTimeLists)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    #Es necesario estar al pendiente de la IP del robot para moficarla
    parser.add_argument("--ip", type=str, default="nao.local",
                        help="Robot IP address. On robot or Local Naoqi: use '127.0.0.1'.")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=9559,
                        help="Naoqi port number")

    args = parser.parse_args()
        # Inicializamos proxys.
    try:
        proxy = ALProxy("ALMotion", "nao.local", 9559)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Could not create proxy to ALMotion"
        print "Error was: ", e

    try:
        postureProxy = ALProxy("ALRobotPosture", "nao.local", 9559)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Could not create proxy to ALRobotPosture"
        print "Error was: ", e

    try:
        ttsProxy = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech" , "nao.local", 9559)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Could not create proxy to ALTextToSpeech"
        print "Error was: ", e

    try:
        memory = ALProxy("ALMemory" , "nao.local", 9559)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Could not create proxy to ALMemory"
        print "Error was: ", e

    try:
        connection_url = "tcp://" + args.ip + ":" + str(args.port)
        app = qi.Application(["SoundProcessingModule", "--qi-url=" + connection_url])
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("Can't connect to Naoqi at ip \"" + args.ip + "\" on port " + str(args.port) +".\n"
               "Please check your script arguments. Run with -h option for help.")
        sys.exit(1)

    MySoundProcessingModule = SoundProcessingModule(app)
    app.session.registerService("SoundProcessingModule", MySoundProcessingModule)
    MySoundProcessingModule.startProcessing()
```

The robot dances according to the RMS level captured from the front mic, but I need to stop it at anytime when the head sensor (or any sensor) is touched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of subscribing to TouchChanged, you can subscribe to the head only with the 3 events (for the 3 tactile buttons):

- FrontTactilTouched
- MiddleTactilTouched
- RearTactilTouched

They will be raised with value 1 when touch starts, and 0 when touch ends. So you will want to filter and only stop your dance when value is 1.